# Strings in C++: Problems with good() and get()

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I am trying to read from a file. The code I used is

```
      ifstream is;char c;
      is.open("text.txt");
      while(is.good() && !isdigit(is.peek()))
      {     is.get(c)
            word+=c;

       }
```

The problem is that the last character is read twice (why?)
For e.g. if the word in the file is     pink
the value of word becomes pinkk after the loop
Please suggest a solution

Comment: 2 cents: I would suggest that you not put two declarations of different types on the same line. `int i, j, k;` is intuitive and readable your `ifstream` and `char` is not so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always want to check that input was successful **after** you tried to read it. You are checking first when the stream has no idea what kind of value is going to be read. If you want to use `peek()` you should probably test against `std::char_traits<char>::eof()` first, e.g.:

```
for (std::char_traits<char>::int_type c;
     std::char_traits<char>::eof() != (c = in.peek())
     && !std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c); ) {
    ...
}
```

In your setup I would personally use `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` as it is a lot easier, actually:

```
for (std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(in), end;
     it != end && !std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it); ++it) {
    word += *it;
}
```

Note that `char` may be unsigned but `std::isdigit()` requires a positive value. If `char` is signed using my second name typically causes undefined behavior. To avoid this problem the `char` pass to `std::isdigit()` should be cast to `unsigned char` first.

Comment: is there no easier solution?

Comment: @zed111: which part do you consider non-easy?

Comment: @zed111: `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` may be a long name but it is actually quite descriptive. Of course, it isn't a function but a class used to iterate over the characters in a stream. You can use a `typedef` but you'll need to mention its name when using this type. `std::isdigit()` isn't really that long. The one guy which is a bit lengthy is the `static_cast<unsigned char>(c)`. You can avoid that using your own version of `isdigit()`, e.g., `bool my_isdigit(unsigned char c) { return std::isdigiti(c); }`

Comment: :I got a solution : see my ans

Comment: Well, 1. it is wrong: you still need to cast the result of `is.peek()` to `unsigned char` as it won't work if `char` is signed; 2. you might want to measure the difference in performance between the two solutions: I'd be surprised if your approach wouldn't be a lot slower (e.g., taking 4 times as long).

Comment: I agree with 2nd point but the code works; Chris's solution is better

Comment: Passing a signed value as an unsigned parameter NEVER causes undefined behavior -- its always well defined per 4.7 in the C++ spec.  So the explicit `static_cast` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: `std::isdigit()` takes an `int`. If `char` is signed, it may pass a negative value (other then `EOF`) without the `std::static_cast<unsigned char>()`. Note that the restriction won't be in 4.7 of the C++ spec but in the section on `isdigit()` in the C spec (7.4, paragraph 1): "... In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined." Clearly, negative values can't be represented by `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the get() once more inside the loop to check whether its some character or not:
here is the code

```
while(is.good() && !isdigit(is.peek()))
{
   is.get(c);
   word+=c;
   if(is.get(c))
   {
      is.seekg(-1,ios::cur)  //move back get pointer if its not end of file
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#include<cctype>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main() {  
  std::ifstream fp("text.txt");
  std::string word;  
  char c;

  // while I am able to read a char...
  while(fp>>c) {
    //... if the char is a digit, stop reading...
    if(std::isdigit(c))
      break;
    //... otherwise append it to my word string    
    word += c;        
  }
  // close your files (or learn about scope-based destruction)
  fp.close();

  // print the resulting word
  std::cout<<word<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compile: `g++ example.cpp`

Sample input (`text.txt`):

```
a
b
c

d
e
f
8
```

Sample output:

```
abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `is.good()` doesn't become false until AFTER you've had a failed read.  So after you read the last character, `is.good()` is still true and you loop again to read another character (which fails), so you append the same character again.

To avoid this, you need to call `is.good()` AFTER reading (or peeking) at the next character -- if it is false then, there is no next character:

```
  ifstream is;char c;
  is.open("text.txt");
  while(!isdigit(is.peek()) && is.good())
  {     is.get(c)
        word+=c;

  }
```

or the simpler and equivalent:

```
  ifstream is;char c;
  is.open("text.txt");
  while (is >> c && !isdigit(c))
        word+=c;
```